# MySQL to Postgresql backup invalid command due to "`"?

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, quoted-identifier

I have an old backup sql file with `` ` `` in it. When I try to load it via `psql dbname < db_backup.sql` I get an error:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tablename`;
> ```

Is there a way to tell psql to treat `` ` `` like `'`?

Comment: Backticks are invalid in an SQL identifier in standard SQL and Postgres. If at all you would need to make it treat them as double quotes: `"` because that's what the SQL standard uses to quote identifiers. You need to replace the dreaded backticks with double quotes. But if that file is a MySQL backup, there will be a lot more in there that needs adjusting to Postgres.

Answer (score 1):

You should create the dump using `mysqldump --compatible=ansi` to avoid this and other migration incompatibilities. I suggest you make a separate MySQL database using your existing backup as it is, then do a dump with this option to make the compatible one.